# Try & Catch multiple input statements

Tags: java

I am trying to catch `InputMismatchException` of multiple input statements. I realize that it is not working right. should I do single `catch` and `try` for each input statement?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean tue = true;
        int inputNum=0;
        int inputNum2=0;
        int inputNum3=0;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
                inputNum = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter another number: ");
                inputNum2 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter another number");
                inputNum3 = input.nextInt();
                 tue = false;

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter the require text");

            }

        }while (tue);
        System.out.println(inputNum + " "+ inputNum2 + " "+ inputNum3);

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks OK, if they stuff up, then start again.

Comment: what exactly is working properly you have to provide a context

Comment: When I type in a string twice and enter a number, it doesn't recognized the number immediately following the string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is not working for you, but here is how I would implement this:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] inputs = new int[3];//create array for the # of inputs
    for ( int i = 0; i < inputs.length; ) {
        try {
            System.out.println( "Enter Num " + ( i + 1 ) );
            inputs[i] = input.nextInt();
            i++;//only increment if the line above doesnt raise error
        } catch ( InputMismatchException e ) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println( "Only integers allowed, try again" );
        }
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println( inputs[0] + " " + inputs[1] + " " + inputs[2] );
```

To print the entire array:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( String.format( "Input %s was %s", i + 1, inputs[i] ) );
    }
```